# How to accept programming code input for displaying purposes?

Tags: php, html, xss, sql-injection, html-entities

What is the safest way to accept user inputted programming code in PHP, store it in database and display it back with the HTML pre tag?

I currently convert the input to HTML entities, but I somehow think it wouldn't be that easy...

Any suggestions?

Comment: You'd think that something that easy to prevent wasn't so abundant on the internet indeed. It is however about that simple...

Comment: My apologies, I totally misunderstood what you were asking for.  I have deleted my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Programming code is just text; if it's not executed there can't be any harm done.

This means you need to be concerned about:

- Protecting your database from SQL injection. This can be done by escaping the input string (`mysql_real_escape_string()`) or using prepared statements.
- Protecting your users from XSS. This can be done by converting your code to html entities (ie: using [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)), so potentially malicious tags (ie: `<script>`) get converted to text (eg: `&lt;script&gt;`).

Comment: I know, but my concern is whether it's completely safe (from XSS/SQL-Injection) to use only htmlspecialchars() to sanitize the code before it goes into database?

Comment: @Ѓоре If done correctly, yes I *believe* so. I am no security expert, but as long as malicious code can't be executed, you should be fine.

Comment: @Ѓоре Саздовски: You don't need to escape the HTML entities when you're putting the code into the database, but you do need to escape the code using a function provided by your database (like `mysql_real_escape_string()` for MySQL) or your site is open to SQL-injection attacks. Using `htmlspecialchars` is not good enough to protect you against SQL-injection attacks (however it will prevent XSS attacks, and should also be applied to the code before it gets embedded in HTML).

Comment: htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES) - correct enough?

I'm using prepared statements with CodeIgniter.

Comment: Prepared statements will escape the code as before it gets sent to the DB as an SQL statement, so yes, that's fine. I didn't see that you were using them before :-)